# Core data context crash

Tags: multithreading, core-data, thread-safety, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am working on save image to core data. I used image pick to select image,

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let currentDateTime = Date()
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        self.imagePickedBlock?(image,currentDateTime)
    } else {
        print("Something went wrong")
    }

    viewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion:{
            if let addPhotoViewController = self.completionViewController as? AddPhotoViewController {
                guard let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else {return }
                addPhotoViewController.photoViewModel.image = image
            self.viewController?.present(addPhotoViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) 
            }
    })
}
```

and in addPhotoViewController, I have an confirme button to call the following update database method. 
The Photo is an NSManagedObject.

```
  private func updateDatabase(with photoViewModels: [PhotoViewModel]) {
    container?.performBackgroundTask {  [weak self] context in
        for photoViewModel in (self?.photoViewModels)! {
            _ = try? Photo.findOrCreatePhoto(matching: photoViewModel, in: context)
        }
        try? context.save()
        self?.printDatabaseStatistics()
    }
}

And this is the create NSManagedObject method. 

  static func findOrCreatePhoto(matching photoViewModel: PhotoViewModel, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> Photo {
    let request : NSFetchRequest<Photo> = Photo.fetchRequest()
    // request.predicate if Needed
    do {
        let matches = try context.fetch(request)
        if matches.count > 0 {
            return matches[0]
        }
    } catch {
        throw error
    }

    let photo = Photo(context:context) // the crash line 
    photo.image = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photoViewModel.image!, 1)
    photo.uploadDate = photoViewModel.createDate
    photo.text = photoViewModel.description
    //       photo.group = try? Group.findOrCreateGroup(matching: photoViewModel, in: context)
    return photo
}.
```

It marks "Enqueued from com.apple.main-thread", I don't really understand where is the problem exactly about the thread, anyone has idea? Don't hesitate if I didn't explain clear enough :) 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: What problem are you having? Is something wrong in the app when that message appears?

Comment: Since it looks like a threading issue I would start by not running it as a background task and instead call the code inside the closure directly from updateDatabase to see if that removes the crash. Why is it necessary to run this in a separate thread? Also I would suggest you properly handle any thrown errors instead of using try?.

Comment: @TomHarrington hello, the app crash when the message appears